# Bash: center and color text with padding either side of a dynamic terminal width using printf

Tags: bash, format, printf, padding, center

I'm trying to format output using printf to achieve the following:

```sh
----------------------------------- HEADING -----------------------------------
-------------------------------- LONGER HEADING -------------------------------
```

However, my attempts have only resulted in:

```sh
- HEADING -
- LONGERHEADING -
```

My current code looks like:

```
MAGENTA=$(tput setaf 5)
NOCOL=$(tput sgr0)

heading="${1^^}"
width="$(tput cols)"
padlimit=30
if [[ $width -gt 240 ]]; then
    padlimit="$(( $width/8 ))"
fi
padding="$(printf '%0.1s' -{1..$padlimit})"

printf '%s%*.*s %s %*.*s%s\n' "$MAGENTA" 0 "$(((width-2-${#heading})/2))" "$padding" \
 "$heading" 0 "$(((width-2-${#heading})/2))" "$padding" "$NOCOL"
```

If I try to hardcode the `padding` variable's count element, like so:

```sh
MAGENTA=$(tput setaf 5)
NOCOL=$(tput sgr0)

heading="${1^^}"
width="$(tput cols)"
padding="$(printf '%0.1s' -{1..60})"

printf '%s%*.*s %s %*.*s%s\n' "$MAGENTA" 0 "$(((width-2-${#heading})/2))" "$padding" \
"$heading" 0 "$(((width-2-${#heading})/2))" "$padding" "$NOCOL"
```

The results are:

```sh
------------------------------ HEADING ------------------------------
------------------------------ LONGER HEADING ------------------------------
```

I imagine the maths is incorrect in the `printf` statement. However, I'm unsure as to:

1. What the arithmetic in the `printf` statement should be; and
2. Why, when providing a variable to the `padding` variable's count element, it doesn't evaluate?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A qucik look at your script, this will fail `printf '%0.1s' -{1..$padlimit}` because variable expansion happens before brace expansion does, in `bash` at least, paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: There isn't a simple way to repeat a character or string a specifiable number of times with `printf`, either as a command or as a C function.  That makes creating a long line fiddly.  Perl has the `x` operator: `perl -e 'print "-" x 32, "\n"'` prints 32 dashes.  Other scripting languages have a similar syntax.  AFAIK, the `printf` command does not support any similar/equivalent notation.

Comment: Your output shows different line lengths so you are probably not factoring in the length of your strings.  i.e.  `width/2 - length(header) / 2 - 1` is length of the prefix and postfix dashes.  Then you print the space and header between those.

Comment: What you are trying to do is useless, because nowadays terminals do not have a fixed width. Whenever you change the size of your terminal window, the layout you try to achieve gets messed. Ansible is similar silly and whenever I use it, it annoys me.

Answer (score 2):

Just write a for loop and print `-` in the for loop.

```
center() {
     local heading width headinglen padlength i
     heading="$*"
     width="$(tput cols)"
     headinglen=${#heading}
     padlength=$(( (width - 2 - headinglen) / 2 ))
     for ((i = 0; i < padlength; ++i)); do
        printf "-"
     done
     printf " %s " "$heading"
     for ((i = 0; i < padlength; ++i)); do
          printf "-"
     done
     if (( (width - 2 - headinglen) % 2 )); then
          printf "-"
     fi
     printf "\n"
}
center HEADING
center LONGER HEADING
```